# Redirect message for web tab in Lightning

Tags: lightning, tab, redirect

I created a web tab which use an URL but in Lightnning, when I click on my web tab, I get a message that means I have to click on a button to be redirected.

Below is the message :
[image]

However, if I click on the button in the Salesforce classic, I am redirected to the URL as well.

Second question in Lightning, wh my iframe is small whereas I set it with 10 000px?

Thanks

Comment: Both questions are not clear. what is the problem? what are you expecting to get and what do you get that you do not like?

Comment: My problem is why I get this message when I click on the web tab in Lightning but not in Salesforce classic?
I don't would like get this message. I would like to be automatically redirect when I click on the web tab when I am on Lightning.

I hope I am clear.

Thanks